# jsonp error with .json extension

Tags: json, angularjs, jsonp

I am using jsonp to get an external json file from the cloud.  I may be being stupid but if I use this file it throws an error but works if I use a file like http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts

The json also works if I pull it in locally

```
function AppGuides($scope, $http) {

var url = "http://keystone-project.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/documents/AirFrance.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
$http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data){
         $scope.guidedata = data;   
         console.log('success');
    })

     .error(function () {
      console.log('error');
    });


  $scope.ddSelectSelected = {
    Label: "Select an Option",  
    class: "hidden"
  };
}
```

UPDATE WITH FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/a4Rc2/953/

Comment: What is the error then?

Comment: the json is not pulling through.

Comment: What does that mean exactly?

Comment: I am creating a dropdown list that needs to be populated with the json.  When I pull it externally nothing comes through and in the console the console log is showing error rather than success

Comment: Just to be clear, which url works and which url doesn't?

Comment: the url http://keystone-project.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/documents/AirFrance.json doesn't work.

Comment: and that is failing even with the `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` parameter I presume?

Answer (score 0):

After closer inspection and trying the code out myself, I can tell you the error is not in this angular application, but with the server where we try to download the JSON.

A simple GET request to http://keystone-project.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/documents/AirFrance.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK reveals that the Content-Type of the returned data is `application/x-unknown-content-type`, when it should be `application/json`.

The exact error it raises is

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/x-unknown-content-type

This is a server side issue, caused by whoever implemented it.

If you have access to the server code, you should change the Content-Type of the returned data.

If you do not have access, the best you can do is ask whoever does have access to fix this issue.

Comment: how do I find out the content type, I have been told it has been changed but it is still not working, thanks

Comment: You can do a GET request to the url, i use chrome extension Postman for that. the content type has indeed been changed to application/json

Comment: thanks, doesn't seem to be the issue though, as it is still not coming through, http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/a4Rc2/953/

Comment: The error is now related to CORS: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://keystone-project.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/documents/AirFrance.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. ` another thing that needs to be fixed serverside